# Convert TColor to COLORREF

Tags: delphi

Has delphi a RTL function to Convert a TColor to [`COLORREF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183449%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if not how i can convert a TColor to COLORREF?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check the [Graphics.ColorToRGB](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.ColorToRGB) function.

> Converts a TColor value into an RGB
>   representation of the color.
>
> Call ColorToRGB to obtain an RGB
>   representation of a color for using
>   with Windows API calls. ColorToRGB
>   strips away the information that is
>   stored in the highest order bits about
>   which palette to use for colors that
>   are not always available.

Answer (score 4):

Use [`ColorToRGB`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Graphics.ColorToRGB).

Answer (score -2):

Both TColor and COLORREF are 32-bit integers, so no conversion is necessary.

Comment: yes and no. Delphi TColor can hold sentinel values for system colors.

Comment: Conversion is necessary in case of `cl*` constants for system colors (`clBtnFace` etc.), see `ColorToRGB`.

Comment: On the other hand, in the unlikely event you're not using an RGB TColor, you don't want to pass it to ColorToRGB.